# Django, Html: How i can display the (number of page / total pages exist) on a pdf printout rendered

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I have to render an HTML template to pdf as a response working with the framework Django and I want to add a footer containing the **number of pages in the pdf-printout / total number of pages** for example, if I have 2 pages in total, the first page should display to me `1/2`, How I can do that please using HTML!

I have tried with this code :

```
      <footer>
        {%block page_foot%}
        <div style="display: block;margin: 0 auto;text-align: center;">
          page: <pdf:pagenumber />
        </div>
      {%endblock%}
      </footer>
```

But it displays 0 on the first page.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

I recommend [wkhtml2pdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) which allows converting html to PDF and it has such features as having TOC and page numbering.